# C#: how to efficiently introduce "Immutable by default" to C#? Immutable attribute?

Tags: c#, immutability

Reading F# and C# these days, one of the big difference is, F# variants are by default Immutable, most C# reference types are by default mutable.

This brings to a question, how to efficiently introduce this "Immutable as by default" to C# coding? er... i mean C# 4.0..

What came to my mind is an "Immutable Attribute".
So when this is docked to a class, by Aspect, each and every member of the class is checked, so that they are only mutable in constructors.

How do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readonly` keyword is a language-level construct to perform the very action you're requesting. When applied to member variables, they can only be set in the constructor and *must* be set in the constructor.

Comment: This is the opposite -- it is immutable [member variables] *by request* ;-)

Comment: @pst: I think the term is "opt-in immutability," but Jon Skeet will have to verify that one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with F#, but C# does have a readonly keyword that can only be applied to members that are initialized at object creation:

```
public class MyExample
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public MyExample(IDependency dependency)
    {
       _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public IDependency Dependency
    {
      get { return _dependency; }
    }
}
```

The keyword can only be applied to members that are immutable, meaning there's no mechanism to alter them from outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish -- whether you're suggesting a new feature for C# or if you're asking how to implement forcing private variables to be immutable except during construction.

If it's the latter, you could accomplish that by making your private variables `readonly` when you declare them. You can't make every variable you declare "read only" by default, so you'll always have to specify this keyword, but with a bit of discipline when writing new code, it'd get the job done.

One more thing to note: a variable being immutable isn't the same as the object it points to being immutable.

For example,

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly List<string> myList;

    public MyClass()
    { 
        myList = new List<string>(); // okay
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        myList = new List<string>(); // not okay; myList is readonly!
        myList.Add("this will work"); // okay -- the list itself is still mutable
    }
}
```